# SUM and GROUP ing of values from 3 list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have salesperson list. it is a list of dictionary contains names of sales person and vehicle and general values.

```
salesperson_list = [
                    {'salesperson': 'MEER SHAFFIC', 'vehicle': 2084.25, 'general': None}, 
                    {'salesperson': 'SHILPY RAJ', 'vehicle': None, 'general': 7796.25}, 
                    {'salesperson': 'RENJITH P G', 'vehicle': 708.75, 'general': None},
                    {'salesperson': 'KRISHNALAL', 'vehicle': 2388.75, 'general': None},  
                   ]
```

I have 2 manager list .

Fist one is sales manager with middle level employees and another one is sales manager with lower level employees.

```
manager_list_1= [
                 {'MEER SHAFFIC': ['SANJAY', 'SHILPY RAJ']},
                 {'SRIDEVI MADHAVARAJ': ['JITIN', 'FAZIL']}
                ]
```

here key is the sales manager and each values are middle level employees.

```
manager_list_2 = [
                  {'MEER SHAFFIC': ['KRISHNALAL','VINCA', None]},
                  {'SRIDEVI MADHAVARAJ': ['KIRAN', None, None]}
                 ]
```

it is the sales manager with lower level employees.

I am actually trying get final like this

```
final_list = [{'salesperson': 'MEER SHAFFIC', 'vehicle': 4473.00, 'general': 7796.25}]
```

The final list contains only **sales manger as salesperson names and sum of middle level and lower level person's vehicle and general value**.

For example **'MEER SHAFFIC' from salesperon_list as salesperson** and values is the  **sum of MEER SHAFFIC'S ,SHILPY RAJ's and KRISHNALAL's values**

I have tried something  but not get a proper result.
Please suggest some **ideas or suggestion for doing this**.
any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution :

```
ultimate_manager_dict = {}
for i in manager_list_1:
    tmp_lst = list(i.values())[0]
    for j in manager_list_2:
        if i.keys()==j.keys():
            tmp_lst += list(j.values())[0]
    tmp_lst = [i for i in tmp_lst if i]
    ultimate_manager_dict.update({list(i.keys())[0] : tmp_lst})
result = []
for manager, sub_ords in ultimate_manager_dict.items():
    veh_lst = []
    gen_lst = []
    for j in salesperson_list:
        if j['salesperson']==manager or j['salesperson'] in sub_ords:
            veh_lst.append(j['vehicle'])
            gen_lst.append(j['general'])
    veh_lst = [i for i in veh_lst if i]
    gen_lst = [i for i in gen_lst if i]
    result.append({'salesperson' : manager, "vehicle" : sum(veh_lst), 'general' : sum(gen_lst)})
print(result)
```

**Output** :

```
[{'salesperson': 'MEER SHAFFIC', 'vehicle': 4473.0, 'general': 7796.25}, 
 {'salesperson': 'SRIDEVI MADHAVARAJ', 'vehicle': 0, 'general': 0}]
```